# word combination: "weekday daytime" or "daytime weekdays"

Tags: word-choice

(1) I have a job during **weekday daytime**, not weeknights.

(2) I have a job during **"daytime weekdays"**, not weeknights.

Which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably say something like "I work during the day, not at night"

Or just say you have a day job.

It's hard to tell from the way you asked. You could just say "I don't work week nights".

Comment: Agreed, without more I would assume that someone with "a day job" is working regular weekday hours.